# Huffman Coding: storing bytes and it's frequency reading it from a file, in C

Tags: c, file-io, byte, huffman-code

I have to store bytes (256 possibilities) and its frequency, reading it from a file and storing it in a struct array.

It has to read simple files like txt, png, mp3 and pdf.I know the Huffman Coding theory, but Im having problems to get the frequency table. I would appreciate tips in C language.

Ex.:  After reading a file, I get three bytes: 0000 1111, 1111 0000, 1111 0000

```
Bytes        Frequency
0000 1111       1
1111 0000       2
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
#define NUM_BYTES 256

typedef struct Node{
    unsigned int frequency;
    char* symbol;
} Node;

GetByteFrequency( char* fileName, Node* table){
    FILE* filep = fopen( fileName, "r" );
    fread(&table, 1, sizeof(char), filep);
    fclose(filep);
}

int main(){
    Node frequencyTable[NUM_BYTES-1];
    GetByteFrequency("text.txt", frequencyTable);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not working how it has to, its just to give an idea of Im doing.

Comment: Why would you store the frequency? That takes more room to store than the symbol length, and that's all you really need anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a simple table of byte frequencies like this:

```
unsigned freq[256] = {0}; /* indexed by byte values */

int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(filep)) != EOF) {
    ++freq[ch];
}
```

After the loop completes, freq[0] is how many times the byte 0 occurred, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are storing your table in text.txt.

What I would suggest is to read/write an entire array at a time which would save you some problems of parsing the file.

For example you can have

```
char freqTable[NUM_BYTES];
FILE* filep = fopen("data.bin", "wb");
fwrite(freqTable, sizeof(char), NUM_BYTES, filep);
```

and then read the array directly

```
FILE* filep = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
fread(freqTable, sizeof(char), NUM_BYTES, filep);
```

notice that the data is stored as binary, so no text parsing is needed

Comment: I dont want to write the table as text in a disc, but store the Nodes in RAM memory (array). "text.txt" could also be "music.mp3" that I need to read its bytes and the frequency of each one.